# Logic error involving Aces in blackjack code

Tags: java

So I'm currently writing a blackjack program and the program runs completely fine and gives the correct outputs unless an ace is added and that ace puts you over 21 total score. This happens not only for the user's hand but also for the dealer's hand. I'm pretty sure that the error occurs in the first method I created countTotal. 
Here's the blackjack class:

```
public class Blackjack {

    static int total = 0;
    static int deal = 0;

    public static int countTotal(Card[] count) {
        int frank = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) 
        frank = count[i].getRank().getValue() + frank;  
        if (frank > 21) {
            for(int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
                if ((count[x].getRank().getValue() == 11) && (frank >21)) 
                    frank = frank - 10; break;
            }
        }
        deal = frank;
        return frank;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myTotal = 0;

        CardDeck bjack = new CardDeck();
        bjack.shuffle();

        Card[] myCards = new Card[11];
        myCards[0] = bjack.nextCard();
        myCards[1] = bjack.nextCard();
        total = 2;

        Card[] dealCards = new Card[11];
        dealCards[0] = bjack.nextCard();
        dealCards[1] = bjack.nextCard();

        System.out.println("Your starting cards are " + myCards[0] + " and " + myCards[1] + 
                " for a total of " + countTotal(myCards));

        System.out.println("\nThe dealer's starting card is " + dealCards[0]);

        System.out.print("\n\nType 0 to stay and 1 to hit. --->     ");
        int hit = scan.nextInt();



        for(int i = 2; hit == 1; i++){
            myCards[i] = bjack.nextCard();      
            total++;

            System.out.print("Your cards are " );
            for (int j = 0; j < total; j++) {
                System.out.print(myCards[j] + " ");
                if (j + 2 == total)
                    System.out.print("and ");
                if (j + 1 == total)
                    System.out.print("for a total of " + countTotal(myCards));
            }
            System.out.println("");

            if (countTotal(myCards) < 21) {
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to hit again? Type 0 to stay and 1 to hit --->    ");
            hit = scan.nextInt();
            }
            else if (countTotal(myCards) == 21) {
                System.out.println("\nCongratulations you are at 21!");
                hit = 0;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("\nYou went over 21 and lost!");
                hit = 0;
            }
        }
        myTotal = total;
        total = 2;
        if (countTotal(myCards) <= 21) {
        System.out.println("\n\nThe dealer's cards are " +  dealCards[0] + " and " + dealCards[1] + " for a total of " + countTotal(dealCards));

        for (int i = 2; countTotal(dealCards) < 17; i++) {
            dealCards[i] = bjack.nextCard();
            total++;
            System.out.print("\nThe dealer's cards are " );
            for (int j = 0; j < total; j++) {
                System.out.print(dealCards[j] + " ");
                if (j + 2 == total)
                    System.out.print("and ");
                if (j + 1 == total)
                    System.out.print("for a total of " + countTotal(dealCards) + "\n");
                }
            }
        deal = countTotal(dealCards);
        total = myTotal;
        int my = countTotal(myCards);

        if ((my > deal) && (my < 22))
            System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations you beat the dealer in blackjack!");
        else if (my == deal)
            System.out.println("\n\nYou and the dealer tied. Good game!");
        else if ((deal > my) && (deal < 22))
            System.out.println("\n\nThe dealer beat you, Nice try!");
        else
            System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations you beat the dealer in blackjack!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly happens then? Can you manually feed your program with needed cards to demonstrate the wrong output, explain what is wrong and what should be the correct output?

Comment: This is an example output-                                                              
Your starting cards are Seven of Spades and Three of Spades for a total of 10

The dealer's starting card is Jack of Clubs

Type 0 to stay and 1 to hit. --->     1
Your cards are Seven of Spades Three of Spades and Two of Diamonds for a total of 12

Would you like to hit again? Type 0 to stay and 1 to hit --->    1
Your cards are Seven of Spades Three of Spades Two of Diamonds and Ace of Hearts for a total of 23
You went over 21 and lost!    Instead of adding the ace as a one, it adds it as an 11

Comment: And? What exactly is wrong and what would be the right output?

Comment: The correct output would be - Your cards are Seven of spades three of spades two of diamonds and ace of hearts for a total of 13. Would you like to hit again, etc

Comment: The problem is that right now, the program returns 23 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
  if ((count[x].getRank().getValue() == 11) && (frank >21)) 
    frank = frank - 10; 
  break;
}
```

you have `break` outside of `if`. As a result your `for` loop executes always just 1 time. You check `count[0]` if it is equal to 11 (it is not), and then you immediately break out of loop. Change the code as follows:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
  if ((count[x].getRank().getValue() == 11) && (frank >21)) {
    frank = frank - 10; 
    break;
  }
}
```

This is the example why you have to ALWAYS use braces with `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, definitely noted for next time